# Aurelia click.delegate not always firing within repeater

Tags: aurelia

I can't pin down this issue but it happens about 1/5 of the time.

I have a click.delegate method within a repeat.for, sometimes the click.delegate method is not fired, and I don't get any errors/warnings.

In the view

```
<ul id="chart-data-set-options" class="dropdown-menu chart-options-list">
                                <li
                                        class="${(type.value === chartDataSet ? 'active' : '')}"
                                        repeat.for="dataSet of dataSets">
                                    <a click.delegate="$parent.eventChartDataSetChanged(dataSet.value)">${dataSet.title}</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

In the VM

```
dataSets = [
    {
        value: RankValueType.RANK,
        title: "Rank",
        shortName: "Rank"
    }, {
        value: RankValueType.RANK_CHANGE,
        title: "Daily Rank Change",
        shortName: "Change"
    }, {
        value: RankValueType.RANK_7_DAY,
        title: "7 Day Moving Avg Rank",
        shortName: "7 Day"
    }, {
        value: RankValueType.RANK_30_DAY,
        title: "30 Day Moving Avg Rank",
        shortName: "30 Day"
    }];
```

I have tried with and without '$parent', doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Works for me. Here is a GistRun: https://gist.run/?id=8dfe873bdbca0a30211accd6e58b7dcd

Comment: Thanks for doing that Jeff. Yes it does work there on Gist. I am trying to work out what the difference between the code is. Obvious differences are 1:I've got an enum, 2: I've got a lot more going on the page already - maybe Aurelia is too slow to react in time to the button. 3: there is bootstrap CSS to show the options in that. Any other ideas? I'll try stripping down my page until it works!

Comment: What else is the page doing that might be slowing things down? Do you have a lot of calculated values being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the exact cause of the issue but I got around it by removing the 'a' element and I also renamed my 'type' variable.

Working version

```
<li
                                        class="${(dataSet.value === chartDataSet ? 'active' : '')}"
                                        repeat.for="dataSet of dataSets"
                                        click.delegate="$parent.eventChartDataSetChanged(dataSet.value)">
                                    ${dataSet.title}
                                </li>
```

Comment: Well that is odd. Could it be the missing href="#" in the 'a' element?

Comment: I tried with and without the href="#" so that wasn't the cause.

Comment: I had css ':hover' rules (from bootstrap.css and a little custom.css) that covered both the 'li' and the 'a' elements. I think that somehow this was causing the issue, I played for a long time and couldn't pin it down though.